# Convert from Hexa value to color name in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, colors, hex, color-scheme

is there a way to convert from **Hex value** to the **color name** using any package in flutter?

Comment: Just convert your hex to `int` and create a `Color(intValueOfHex)`.

Comment: @rickimaru OP wants a color *name*.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: If you talk about the material colors, there is no way to get the color name from the hex value. You have to make your own class to do that

Answer (score 1):

There is this package called [color_convert 1.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/color_convert) that should help? However, it only takes color names found on [a GitHub list](https://github.com/colorjs/color-name/blob/master/index.js) from what I understand.
So I don't think it can be used for a wide range of colors (the GitHub list has around 147 colors in RGB which I think can be converted to HexCode and then Text), but you could certainly take this color converter and work off of it to build your own for more specific colors.
As of current I don't think there is a package that does exactly what you are looking for, but this is a good start.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve without using any pacakges.You can convert hex color as follows:

```
 class HexColor extends Color {
  static int _getColorFromHex(String hexColor) {
    hexColor = hexColor.toUpperCase().replaceAll("#", "");
    if (hexColor.length == 6) {
      hexColor = "FF" + hexColor;
    }
    return int.parse(hexColor, radix: 16);
  }

  HexColor(final String hexColor) : super(_getColorFromHex(hexColor));
}
```

Then access as:

```
 static Color cardColor = HexColor('#D4AA3A');
```

Comment: OP stated that they want a color *name*.